# Java - an assignment for a beginner. Using modulo to find divisibility and creating a loop afterwards

Tags: java, if-statement, division, modulo

I've just started my adventure with developing and I've stumbled upon my first bump. Could anyone help me solve this assignment for the beginners or just show me how to start and what to use in variables?

Write code that will:

1. Check if a number, *X*, is divisible by a number, *7*, without a remainder.
2. If so - in the console print this (instead of showing *X*):

   > Number 7 is a divisor of number X
3. If not - in the console print this:

   > Number 7 is NOT a divisor of number X

Here's what I've got written so far:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int number = 7;
    if (number % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number 7 is a divisor of number X");
    } else {
         System.out.println("Number 7 is NOT a divisor of number X");
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us your try please and we will help ;)

Comment: I've edited my post to show you guys what I've tried but I don't think its enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am in free time and give you a sample:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //declare library
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int number;     //declare a variable named 'number' has type int
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         number = scanner.nextInt(); //assign value to 'number' via keyboard
         if(number%7==0){
             System.out.println("Number 7 is a divider of number X");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("Number 7 is a divider of number X");
         }
     }
}
```